# Применение методов класса к переменной

Tags: python

Есть такой код:

```
connection = mysql("127.0.0.1", "test")

connection.dispense('users')
```

где `mysql(__init__)` подключается к базе данных

метод `dispense()` создаёт таблицу если её нет

как можно сделать так, чтобы я, например положил его в отдельную переменную и уже по переменной добавлял новые поля. Пример кода (псевдокод):

```
users = connection.dispense('users')

users.name = "Alex"
user.login = "test"
user.password = "qwerty"
```

Где `name`, `password` и `login` названия полей.
Как и возможно ли это вообще реализовать?

Comment: Как например в RedBean PHP

Comment: Обычно добавление новых таблиц и полей реализуется с помощью миграций. Например, можно использовать alembic https://pypi.org/project/alembic/

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте про ORM. Например, Peewee или SqlAlchemy. Это как раз то, что вы ищите.

Comment: А можно использовать это на уровне декораторов например? Потому что в проектах, которые вы перечислили, код, в котором может разобраться лишь тот, кто его писал) Можете подсказать как сделали бы вы?

Comment: Есть ли какая-то альтернатива оператора -> как в PHP, но в питоне?